# types of joints to design a robot model

Tags: ros, joint, rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi is there any tutorial or website where i can find details about "**types of joints**"
to design a robot model in rviz and how they work and coded ???...........i have already searched urdf tutorials i cant find it there

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38330/types-of-joints-to-design-a-robot-model/) by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[From ROSCon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns&t=10m7s)
(jump to 10:07 if the link doesn't do that for you automatically)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently on the [urdf wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf) the link to the [XML specifications subpage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML) (where in section *joints* all types are described) has been accidentally removed. Fixed that.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1